# Complex Matrix multiplication

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to  do this operation bellow but it is really slow for a large matrix if you use for loops.
Can someone help to do this operation? We know that `Y`,`A`,`M` are matrix and `mean` is a column.

Thank you

```
Y=zeros(s,y);
for i=1:y
   Y(:,i)=A*(M(:,i)-mean); 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Y = A * (M - repmat(mean, 1, y));
```

Comment: What in case when we have the loop as below     Y(:,i)=A*M(:,i)-mean; instead of Y(:,i)=A*(M(:,i)-mean);   how can I edit your answer for  this case